# Async function without return different behavior?

Tags: javascript

Here is an example:

```
let test = async () => {
  let res = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
}

console.log(test()) // Promise {<resolved>: undefined}
```

The output is `Promise {<resolved>: undefined}` because i didn't return anything, and it resolved with `undefined`. I understand this.

Now, here is the second example:

```
let test = async () => {
  let res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
}

console.log(test()) // Promise {<pending>}
```

I'm still not returning anything, and  i get `Promise {<pending>}`. Why is it happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that in your first example, the `fetch` call is not awaited, and it simply returns a promise object that is assigned to the `res` variable, and then, the function immediately returns. The promise that `fetch` returns is lost.

The second example when you use the `await` keyword, the async function is "paused" to wait until the `fetch` call resolves, and it assigns the resolved value (the fetch response) to the variable.

Even if you are not returning anything, whenever you await a promise inside an async function, it will wait until it resolves or rejects.

If the promise you are awaiting rejects, it will cause an exception within the function that will end up in a rejection of the implicitly returned promise.